# Non-existence of nowhere vanishing vector field on even dimensional sphere

Tags: homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes

I want to show that for even dimensional spheres, there does not exist a nowhere vanishing vector field, namely a non-trivial cross section of its tangent bundle. I am wondering how elementary the proof could be. While I know this should follow from Lefschetz fixed-point theorem (I have seen the proof when $n=2$ a long time ago), I believe there should be easier proofs available.

It seems this theorem follows from standard differential topology tools (like Poincare-Hopf theorem and computing the Euler characteristic). And similarly one may use tools like Euler class. But is there a more elementary proof available (at the level of singular homology and cohomology)?

Here is a "cyclic type argument". Assuming I can show that if a nonwhere vanshing vector field exists, then the antipodal map must be homotopically equivalent to the identity map, then I would be able to prove the original statement since the antipodal map for even dimensional sphere has degree $-1$. However, I do not know how to prove the first statement without passing to even and odd cases. So this does not really help very much.

Sorry if this question is too trivial. I am looking for a hint (not an answer).

Reference:
Milnor&Stasheff, Problem 2-B

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem

Comment: Proof by contradiction: Assume there is such a vector field. Let $v_x$ denote the vector at the point $x$. The homotopy $H:S^2\times[0,1]\to S^2$ is defined by: $H(x,t)$ is the point $t\pi$ radians away from $x$ along the great circle defined by $v_x$. This gives a homotopy between the identity and the antipodal map on $S^2$. (Can you complete the proof from here?)

Comment: Dear Sanath: I think $v_{x}$ is a tangent vector field, not a smooth section of the normal vector bundle.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry about that.

Comment: Cor. 1.26 in Vick's [Homology Theory](http://dmat.cfm.cl/files/Libri/vick.pdf) is pretty elementary.  (It is your "typical cyclic argument."  The proofs of the results you reference are immediately before it, and also elementary and at the singular homology level.)

Comment: In particular, see Prop. 1.23 on page 28.  Also:

* "'cylcic type argument"

Comment: Ralph Mellish: Thanks! I have never read Vick's book before. This is a wonderful introduction to something I do not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Posting an answer to get this off the unanswered queue.)

Ralph Mellish mentions that proof of the kind requested can be found as Cor 1.26 in Vick's [*Homology Theory*](http://dmat.cfm.cl/files/Libri/vick.pdf).

I note the same proof appears as theorem 2.28 in Chapter 2.2 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*.